# DataSource failing to instantiate

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to connect to an external mssql database but I am getting a bean instantiation exception. I have tried annotating my main class with @EnableJpaRepo, excluding DataSourceAutoConfiguration etc. I tried using myBatis and it worked but I've been instructed to use Jpa. Thank you.

My .yml file:

```
ansir.datasource:
  schema: schema
  jdbc-url: jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER:PORTNO;databaseName=DB;encrypt=false 
  username: root
  password: pwd
  driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  hikari.maximum-pool-size: 10
  hikari.pool-name: HikariPool-ANSIR
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
```

my config class:

```
@Value("${ansir.datasource}")
private String SCHEMA_NAME;

@Value("${ansir.datasource.jdbc-url}")
private String jdbcUrl;

@Value("${ansir.datasource.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${ansir.datasource.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${ansir.datasource.driver-class-name}")
private String driverClassName;

@Value("${ansir.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size}")
private String maxPool;

@Value("${ansir.datasource.hikari.pool-name}")
private String poolName;

@Value("${ansir.datasource.jpa.show-sql}")
private String showSql;

@Value("${ansir.datasource.jpa.hibernate.dialect}")
private String hibernateDialect;

@Value("${ansir.datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
private String ddl;
private final Environment env;

@Autowired
public ANSIRConfiguration(Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("ansir.datasource")
public DataSource ansirDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName(env.getProperty(driverClassName))
            .url(env.getProperty(jdbcUrl))
            .username(env.getProperty(username))
            .password(env.getProperty(password))
            .build();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager ansirTransactionManager(@Qualifier("ansirEntityManager") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean) {

    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
            entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}


@Bean("ansirEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ansirEntityManager(@Qualifier("ansirDataSource")DataSource ansirDataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(ansirDataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.autonation.ca.client.ansir.entity");
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("ansir");

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter

            = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
            env.getProperty(ddl));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
            env.getProperty(hibernateDialect));
    properties.put("hibernate.proc.param_null_passing", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sq", showSql);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

}

my stack trace:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1541)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:667)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:591)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.attemptFromContextLoader(HikariConfig.java:970)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperty.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:460)
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperties.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:355)
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:190)
at com.autonation.ca.client.ansir.config.ANSIRConfiguration.ansirDataSource(ANSIRConfiguration.java:64)
at com.autonation.ca.client.ansir.config.ANSIRConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$307494cc.CGLIB$ansirDataSource$2()
at com.autonation.ca.client.ansir.config.ANSIRConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$307494cc$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d0e3b4d8.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
at com.autonation.ca.client.ansir.config.ANSIRConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$307494cc.ansirDataSource()
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)

Thank you.

Comment: remove @Autowired from your constructor and test again? log on std shows  constructor not instantiated correctly.

Comment: @AmirRad I have tried it but it did not work.

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: Your JDBC URL looks suspicious: `jdbc-url: jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER:;databaseName=DB;encrypt=false`. That `:;` suggests you are missing a port number. The colon (`:`) should be followed by a port number, or should be removed from the URL string. You can test your URL string separately to make sure it is valid.

Comment: I echo what @Oliver wrote when they mentioned (a) you should try to improve the formatting of your question; and (b) you should provide a MRE - remove every line of code which is not relevant to your problem. You have not done either of those, so far.

Comment: @andrewJames I have edited now. Concerning the url, it has a port a port number

Comment: OK - that is not what I meant - but thank you for the edits, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change application.yml file to application.properties with these config,

```
ansir.datasource.schema= schema
ansir.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER;databaseName=DB;encrypt=false
ansir.datasource.username=root
ansir.datasource.password=pwd
ansir.datasource.driver-class-name= com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
ansir.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
ansir.datasource.hikari.pool-name= HikariPool-ANSIR
ansir.datasource.jpa.show-sql= true
ansir.datasource.jpa.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
ansir.datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= none
```

period is not normal use in application.yml file.

Comment: I get this error when I use a .properties file: "Parameter 1 of constructor in com.autonation.ca.service.AppointmentService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found."

Comment: Use @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="your.package", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf") on related package.

Comment: Thank you @Amir Rad. I used EnableJpaRepositories and it worked.